# Serviço de Aplicativo conectar a banco de dados MySQL externo do azure

Tags: mysql, wordpress, microsoft-azure

Estou tentando conectar o wordpress que está rodando em um Serviço de Aplicativo no Azure.
No domínio principal tenho uma aplicação ASP NET MVC e configurei uma aplicação para rodar o wordpress no mesmo domínio.
O PHP está funcionando normalmente, pois, consigo executar arquivos com esta extensão. O problema está ocorrendo quando tento conectar a um banco de dados MySQL que não está rodando no azure.
Fiz um teste em minha máquina local (IIS) e a conexão ocorre normalmente.

Mensagem de erro

> Warning: mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a
>   period of time, or established connection failed because connected
>   host has failed to respond. in D:\home\site\wwwroot\blog\teste.php on
>   line 20 Connection failed: A connection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   established connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond.

Código utilizado para testar a conexão

```
<?php
$link = new mysqli('ENDERCOIP:3306', 'USUARIO', 'SENHA', 'BANCO_DADOS');
if (!$link) {
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
mysql_close($link);
?>
```

Acredito que o azure está bloqueando as requisições. Há alguma configuração que posso fazer para liberar as portas do MySQL?

Comment: Onde está esse MySQL?

Comment: Ele está em uma hospedagem compartilhada que tenho.